# How to Manage Google API Errors in Python

Tags: python, google-api, google-bigquery

I'm currently doing a lot of stuff with BigQuery, and am using a lot of `try... except...`. It looks like just about every error I get back from BigQuery is a apiclient.errors.HttpError, but with different strings attached to them, i.e.:

`<HttpError 409 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/some_id/datasets/some_dataset/tables?alt=json returned "Already Exists: Table some_id:some_dataset.some_table">`

`<HttpError 404 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/some_id/jobs/sdfgsdfg?alt=json returned "Not Found: Job some_id:sdfgsdfg">`

among many others. Right now the only way I see to handle these is to run regexs on the error messages, but this is messy and definitely not ideal. Is there a better way?

Comment: It looks like the Exception has a few [additional attributes](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/source/browse/apiclient/errors.py#35) that you could rely on -- Specifically, you could (try to) parse the JSON from the `error.content` and work with that.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

BigQuery is a REST API, the errors it uses follow standard HTTP error conventions.

In python, an HttpError has a resp.status field that returns the HTTP status code.
As you show above, 409 is 'conflict', 404 is 'not found'.

For example:

```
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
try:
   ...
except HttpError as err:
  # If the error is a rate limit or connection error,
  # wait and try again.
  if err.resp.status in [403, 500, 503]:
    time.sleep(5)
  else: raise
```

The response is also a json object, an even better way is to parse the json and read the error reason field:

```
if err.resp.get('content-type', '').startswith('application/json'):
    reason = json.loads(err.content).get('error').get('errors')[0].get('reason')
```

This can be:
notFound, duplicate, accessDenied, invalidQuery, backendError, resourcesExceeded, invalid, quotaExceeded, rateLimitExceeded, timeout, etc.

Comment: If I get the reason as invalid, what should be done?

Comment: How do you do this in python 3.7? This seems not to be valid syntax unless you are using version 2

Answer (score 14):

Google Cloud now provides exception handlers:

```
from google.api_core.exceptions import AlreadyExists, NotFound
try:
    ...
except AlreadyExists:
    ...
except NotFound:
    ...
```

This should prove more exact in catching the details of the error.

Please reference this source code to find other exceptions to utilize: http://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/google/api_core/exceptions.html

Comment: Those 400 and 500 errors can be caught through the `Forbidden` and `InternalServerError` exceptions respectively.