# python : capturing errors for non base

Tags: python, error-handling, google-api

I have the code below that generates an error :

> googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 429 when requesting
> https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1FJiVwQu2AAca06dpkoh20zQYGyyQ8RBZJ8xWZgGlcS4/values/1.%20Forge%20Operator%20shift%20form%20-%20v1.12%211%3A200?alt=json
> returned "Quota exceeded for quota metric 'Read requests' and limit
> 'Read requests per minute per user' of service 'sheets.googleapis.com'
> for consumer 'project_number:1'.". Details: "[{'@type':
> 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo', 'reason':
> 'RATE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED', 'domain': 'googleapis.com', 'metadata':
> {'quota_limit': 'ReadRequestsPerMinutePerUser', 'consumer':
> 'projects/1', 'service': 'sheets.googleapis.com',
> 'quota_metric': 'sheets.googleapis.com/read_requests'}}]">

and I want to catch the error to exponentially back off from calling the API too frequently.  However, when I run the script, I'm not sure how to target this particular error.  In the "except" line I have tried HttpError, 429, 'googleapiclient.errors.HttpError'.  How do i capture just the error above?

```
# gets data from google spreadsheet 
def fetch_data_from_google_spreadsheet(SPREADSHEET_ID, google_credentials):
    
    # looks at connecting to the google api service 
    # If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
    SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly']

    try : 
        service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=google_credentials)

        # Call the Sheets API
        sheet = service.spreadsheets()
        
        # Returns all sheets (tabs) in a spread sheet

        time.sleep(3)
        return_sheet_ID = sheet.get(spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID, ranges=None, includeGridData=None, x__xgafv=None).execute()

        # extracts just the sheets 
        individual_sheets = return_sheet_ID.get("sheets")

        list_of_dict_sheets = []

        # loops through each tab and returns the rows within each sheet 
        for item in individual_sheets:
            # returns the sheet names to pass into sheet values
            RANGE_NAME = item.get("properties").get("title") + "!" + "1" + ":" + str(item.get("properties").get("gridProperties").get("rowCount"))
            time.sleep(3)
            # returns the rows within the spreadsheets 
            list_of_dict_sheets.append (sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID,
                                    range=RANGE_NAME).execute())
        df2 = None 
        # loops through each sheet and returns the details  
        for each_sheet in list_of_dict_sheets:
            df = pd.DataFrame(each_sheet.get("values"))
            df = df.rename(columns=df.iloc[0])
            df = df.iloc[1:]
            df2 = pd.concat([df,df2])
        return df2
    except Exception as e:
        print("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Manage Google API Errors in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23945784/how-to-manage-google-api-errors-in-python)

Comment: yeah that works :-)   used the following code : 

    except HttpError as err:
        # If the error is a rate limit or connection error,
        # wait and try again.
        if err.resp.status in [429]:
            print ("creating delay for google api : ", error_timeout) 
            time.sleep(error_timeout)
            error_timeout = error_timeout * 2 
            pass