# How can I catch the code of HttpError from google calendar API batch callback in Python?

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

Based on this example from
https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/epy/googleapiclient.http.BatchHttpRequest-class.html

How can I catch what HttpError code I get from exception (if exception is not None)?

```
from googleapiclient.http import BatchHttpRequest

  def list_animals(request_id, response, exception):
    """Do something with the animals list response."""
    if exception is not None:
      if exception.code == 410:
        """DO MY THING"""
    else:
      # Do something with the response.
      pass

  def list_farmers(request_id, response, exception):
    """Do something with the farmers list response."""
    if exception is not None:
      if exception.code == 410:
        """DO MY THING"""
    else:
      # Do something with the response.
      pass

  service = build('farm', 'v2')

  batch = BatchHttpRequest()

  batch.add(service.animals().list(), list_animals)
  batch.add(service.farmers().list(), list_farmers)
  batch.execute(http=http)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `exception` variable stores a [Google HTTPError object](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/epy/googleapiclient.errors.HttpError-class.html).

Here is another post which describes how to work with these exception objects: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23962706